# How can I safely rename a property on a class representing a SQLite entity in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I have a class Foo with property Id like so

```
public class Foo
{
   [PrimaryKey]
   public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

But I would like to rename Id to be FooId. When I do this and reinstall my Xamarin app as an update, I get the following error on insert:

```
table Foo has no column named FooId
```

Obviously, the table definition is changing and I am missing some explicit command to the sqlite db to aid that process.

Of note, it works fine if I delete the app and reinstall it fresh.

Using SQLite-net PCL version 1.1.1 installed from nuget.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I would suggest using [SQLite-net-pcl](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) instead of SQLite.Net-PCL (notice the dash between SQLite and Net) because of [issues](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/issues/311) on Android 6.0+ that have never been fixed (as far as I know at least) which would prevent your app from running on Android 6.0+. The APIs are almost identical but you would have more APIs available after switching.

To fix the issue of column/model property renames and the same issue of adding columns/model properties after data is already in the table, I attempt to detect the exception. If it is detected, the code drops the table, recreates it, and reinserts all data.

I use a generic repository so it makes it easier but the code below should give you an idea. Also, SQLite.Net-PCL does not have the `DropTableAsync()` API so you would have to use `ExecuteAsync()` if you do not change libraries:

```
public static async Task<string> UpdateTableSchemaAsync<T>() where T : class, new() {
    IGenericRepository<T> genericRepo = new GenericRepository<T>();

    try {
        List<T> savedObjects = await genericRepo.AllAsync(); //Collect all current records before dropping table

        if(savedObjects != null && savedObjects.Count > 0) {
            await genericRepo.DropTableAsync();
            await genericRepo.CreateTableAsync();

            // You could do some data transformation here if necessary, such as transferring all Foo.FooId values to the Foo.Id column

            await genericRepo.InsertAllAsync(savedObjects); //Insert all objects back
        } else {
            await genericRepo.DropTableAsync();
            await genericRepo.CreateTableAsync();
        }

        return null;
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Debug.WriteLine("\nIn ModelHelpers.UpdateTableSchemaAsync() - Exception attempting to recreate " + typeof(T).Name + " data:\n" + ex.GetBaseException() + "\n");
        return "An error occurred while attempting to update the " + typeof(T).Name + " data.";
    }
}
```

To use the above I pass all Insert or Update operations through a method as an `Func` which puts the `Func` inside a `try`/`catch` to detect a `SQLiteException` and look for the word **column** in the `Exception.Message` (yes I know this is lame), if that is detected, we run the `UpdateTableSchemaAsync()` method and attempt to execute the passed in Insert or Update `Func` again:

```
//Again this method is within a generic repository so T is defined through the generic repo instantiation
public async Task<TResult> ExecuteSafeAsync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> taskFunc, [CallerMemberName] string caller = "") {
    try {
        return await taskFunc.Invoke();
    } catch(SQLiteException sqlException) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\nIn GenericRepository.ExecuteSafeAsync() via " + caller + " - Exception attempting to run query on " + typeof(T).Name + "\n" + sqlException.GetBaseException() + "\n");

        if(sqlException.Message.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("column")) {    //The error being searched for is "no such column: <column name>"
            try {
                await ModelHelpers.UpdateTableSchemaAsync<T>();
            } catch(Exception ex) { //If this fails for what ever reason, we do not want the ModelHelpers.UpdateTableSchemaAsync() method's exception being the one that gets detected upstream
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\nIn GenericRepository.ExecuteSafeAsync() via " + caller + " - Exception attempting to run rebuild " + typeof(T).Name + " table after detecting SQLite Exception\n" + ex.GetBaseException() + "\n");
            }

            return await taskFunc.Invoke(); //Now that the table has been recreated lets try to run it again
        }

        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your recommended library is what we are using. But, as you noted by the similar names, I can see the confusion. I attempted something like your solution, but values are lost in the gathering of savedObjects because the column whose name changed is all nulls. It seems I need to somehow get the values out of that table into a List of Object (although I couldn't get this to work either) or the like. Any suggestions?

Comment: @GarrettDanielDeMeyer Correct, so when you change the column/model property name, you will need to keep the old column/model property name because it has the old values in it. Then you will need to pull out the values and move them to the new column name.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the [Column()] Annotation

```
public class Foo
{
   [Column("Id")]
   [PrimaryKey]
   public int FooId {get; set;}
}
```

See

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/column-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx